# PHP: "No such file or directory" but file exists

Tags: php, include

Im trying to include a left hand side menu and im using...

`<?php include "/public_html/includes/includes-clients/menu.php" ?>`

to include it and i get the whole "No such file or directory" nonsense, but when i grab the that path to the file and manually put it in the search bar it takes me right there. I am a bit of a noob so be gentle.

Additional info

I cant access any other files in "includes-clients"

Using "../../includes/includes-clients/menu.php" does work but i would like to have it referenced from the root.

Comment: "but file exists"—are you _entirely_ sure? The leading `/` is significant. Do you have a directory called `public_html/` at the top level of the filesystem that PHP can see? Your relative URL starts with two levels of `..`, which would be a directory above `public_html/`, so I don't think so.

Comment: Just remove the "/public_html/" part from include path

Comment: `include "/public_html/....` is missing something before that, something like `include "/var/usr/public_html/...`. Use `phpinfo()` to see what your actual server root for the user is. You'll get your answer.